# C# HttpClient Post cannot get full response

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpclient

i am having problem with getting full response from post request. 
Specifically my problem is that in Fiddler i got full response(responses below) and in .NET i got only part of it.

I am using HttpClient and this is like my code looks like

```
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

in .NET i got this response (serialized to json)

`{"Version":{"Major":1,"Minor":1,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1},"Content":{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Length","Value":["471"]},{"Key":"Expires","Value":["Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"]},{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/json; charset=UTF-8"]}]},"StatusCode":200,"ReasonPhrase":"OK","Headers":[{"Key":"X-Frame-Options","Value":["SAMEORIGIN"]},{"Key":"Pragma","Value":["no-cache"]},{"Key":"Cache-Control","Value":["no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, post-check=0, pre-check=0"]},{"Key":"Date","Value":["Wed, 19 Apr 2017 22:13:15 GMT"]},{"Key":"Set-Cookie","Value":["SD_FRAMEWORK_SESSION=10ktfgcedl5rq427kvmo0sj7v4; path=/","user=abca7451088; expires=Sat, 20-May-2017 22:13:15 GMT; Max-Age=2678400; httponly","password=d30b0cc02736cf891cfca885ff5245bd; expires=Sat, 20-May-2017 22:13:15 GMT; Max-Age=2678400; httponly"]},{"Key":"Server","Value":["Apache"]},{"Key":"Connection","Value":["close"]}],"RequestMessage":{"Version":{"Major":1,"Minor":1,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1},"Content":{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]},{"Key":"Content-Length","Value":["88"]}]},"Method":{"Method":"POST"},"RequestUri":"http://URL.COM/","Headers":[],"Properties":{}},"IsSuccessStatusCode":true}`

but in Fiddler I got this response (in RAW view)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 22:13:15 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: SD_FRAMEWORK_SESSION=10ktfgcedl5rq427kvmo0sj7v4; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: user=abca7451088; expires=Sat, 20-May-2017 22:13:15 GMT; Max-Age=2678400; httponly
Set-Cookie: password=d30b0cc02736cf891cfca885ff5245bd; expires=Sat, 20-May-2017 22:13:15 GMT; Max-Age=2678400; httponly
Content-Length: 471
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"special":{"login":true,"tracking":"\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/url.com\/functions.js\"><\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\nsetPixel ({\n'location':'SIGNUP',\n'product':'test',\n'language':'cz',\n'server-id':'lobby',\n'user-id':'340668',\n'user-email':'abca30132611@mail.col',\n'user-name':'abca7451088'\n});\n<\/script>"},"messages":{"error":[],"warning":[],"success":["V\u00edt\u00e1me V\u00e1s, abca7451088"]}}
```

So, how can I get that special section ("{"special":{"....") in .NET response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler shows response content. You can get content from `HttpResponseMessage` using [ReadAsStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx) method of `HttpContent`:

```
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```